# Pragmatic way to check if trigger exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I am working with postgreSQL and cracking my head to see if a trigger I created actually exists. What is the most pragmatic way of verifying if a certain trigger exists in postgreSQL?

Comment: `select * from pg_trigger`? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-trigger.html  or simply `\d the_table_name` from within `psql`

Comment: Awesome dude. Thanks a bunch. If you want you can post the above comment as answer and I will mark it as correct. You deserve the points.